# What will i write inside my Class.forName if i have jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306

Tags: java, mysql

im just really new to java and i have a  hard time just to connect the database.
thank you for the  help

i tried the derby but my database is in mysql using xampp.

```
 Statement stmnt;
  ResultSet rs;
    try{
       String host = "jdbc:derby://localhost:3306/population";
       String uName= "root";
       String uPass="root";
       Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(host, uName, uPass);
       //execute some sql and load into the result set
       stmnt = con.createStatement();
       String sql = "SELECT * FROM users_admin";
       rs = stmnt.executeQuery(sql);
       //move the cursor the first record and get the data
       rs.next();
       int id = rs.getInt("admin_id");
       String id_admin = Integer.toString(id);
       String username=rs.getString("username");
       String pwd = rs.getString("password");

       ta_user.setText(username);
       ta_pwd.setText(pwd);
       ta_id.setText(id_admin);


   }
    catch( SQLException err ){
        System.out.println( err.getMessage());
    }
```

I've tried that, code in my other sample project and it shows an error:

java.net.ConnectException : Error connecting to server localhost on port 3306 with message Connection refused: connect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good news! You don't need a `Class.forName` and your JDBC driver loaded successfully. Now you need a mysql sever, or derby server you use two different jdbc url(s) in the question, listening on port 3306 to connect to.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need it. `Connection refused` indicates that your driver is working perfectly, and that your MySQL or Derby database server (whichever of the contradictory URLs in your title and question is to be believed) isn't started, or possibly even installed, on the localhost.

Comment: Or, (possibly) the derby server needs to be started. OP included contradictory jdbc url(s) between headline (mysql) and body (derby).